# How to bystep this $watch infinite loop?

Tags: angularjs

In my angularJs file, I have a watch set on a variable that is set by my md-select

```
<md-select ng-model="NC.common.commonType" ng-model-options="{trackBy: '$value.id'}" flex="25" placeholder="Common Type" ng-disabled="!NC.isEdit()">
```

In my controller:

```
scope.$watch('NC.common.commonType', function (new, old) {
        modal.launchModal('Common type changed', '<p>Are you sure?</p>')
        .then((result) => {
            if (!result) {
                vm.module.placementType = angular.copy(oldValue);
        });
    }, true);
```

So when they select another option; it triggers a modal. This modal asks you if you are sure you want to change the modal. If you say no, I set the watched variable back to the old value; and ignore the new value. This triggers the $watch infinite loop.

Comment: when using `ng-model`, use `ng-change` instead of creating a $watch, it will avoid mistakes. I assume you just want to know when NC.common.commonType is edited from the input `<md-select>` .

Comment: Yes, that is right. I need to be able to preserve the old value, incase they say no in the modal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what it looks like with the ng-change

```
<md-select ng-model="NC.common.commonType" ng-value="NC.common.commonType" ng-change="CC.onChange(NC.common.commonType,'{{NC.common.commonType}}')">

        vm.onChange = function(newValue, oldValue) {
        modal.launchModal('Placement type changed', '<p>Are you sure?</p>')
        .then((result) => {
            if (!result) {
                vm.module.placementType = angular.copy(oldValue);

            } 
        });
    };
```

This works without the infinite loop

Answer (score 1):

There maybe a way to do this by changing the way you actually update the model; however, other than possibly finding a way to register/unregister the watch in the if statement; this may not be a very good idea.